# app services status shows QuotaExceeded but when i open quota, everything looks fine

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

when i try to make any api call, after about 2 or 3 calls i start getting the 403 error page and when i go to my azure portal app services, i see the status with QuotaExceeded but when i open the Quotas page, everything looks ok
see attached images
[app services showing QuotaExceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3D5c.png)
[quotas page showing that everything looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtqAy.jpg)

haven´t experienced this before and i don´t even know what to try

if app services status shows QuotaExceeded, when i open the quota page, i should see that a quota has actually reached its limit but instead i see that everything is fine

Comment: Did you send an authorization when you call your API ? Because withour authorization you will always receive this 403 ( unauthorized ) error !

Comment: Like I said it is showing that a quota is exceeded but when I go to the quotas page it shows that everything is fine but looking at the list of app services, the status shows QuotaExceeded. And after the reset time, the api works again but after a few api calls it has the same issue

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same. Looks like a bug in the quota management code. Being Microsoft, it is not suprising I guess.